# Is there a way to get how long a key is being pressed on in MIPS?

Tags: keyboard, mips

I'm making a synth for school, and I want to be able to play a note for the amount of time the key is being pressed on. I already know that syscall 30 will give me system time, but I don't know how to know when the key is no longer pressed on.

Comment: I don't think that QtSPIM or MARS has key-up events on keyboard MMIO.  What environment are you using?

Comment: I'm using mars 4.5, and i'm on windows.

Comment: The plug-in keyboard and display communicate ascii data values not key-down and key-up events, though they can be used via interrupt. You might look into writing a custom [plug-in](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/MarsHelpTools.html), and/or extend existing plug-ins.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some relevant code from the Keyboard and Display Simulator plug-in tool for MARS & [RARS](https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars) (the RISC V version of MARS):

```
private class KeyboardKeyListener implements KeyListener {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        int updatedReceiverControl = readyBitSet(RECEIVER_CONTROL);
        updateMMIOControlAndData(RECEIVER_CONTROL, updatedReceiverControl, RECEIVER_DATA, e.getKeyChar() & 0x00000ff);
        if (updatedReceiverControl != 1) {
            InterruptController.registerExternalInterrupt(EXTERNAL_INTERRUPT_KEYBOARD);
        }
    }


    /* Ignore key pressed event from the text field. */
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    /* Ignore key released event from the text field. */
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

You could alter this code to do something in the lower level events handlers: keyPressed and keyReleased — instead the higher level event: keyTyped.

The idea is that you could supply key code data rather than character data, either at some new MMIO register location -or- hijack the existing receiver data and control locations for key code data instead of character data.